# Names of Angels in Judaism

Tags: names, tanach, malach-angel

What are the names of  angels mentioned in Jewish scriptures ?

Comment: You've got two questions here that I think ought to be separated. I recommend fleshing out the Gavriel one with more about what you mean by "rank" and why you suspect that there might be such a concept, and how Gavriel might fit into it. In the question about angels' names, I recommend that you add information about why you suspect that angels' names may or may not be mentioned in the Bible and why you want to know.

Comment: It would be impossible to answer this because of rashi's comment citing breishis rabba on Breishis 32:30. I am on my phone so I can't cite it properly. Ifyour point is simply to ccatalog names from text you would still have a problem as in some cases, as in this one,  tradition dictates that this is an angel,  not the text.

Comment: א"ר אלעזר בר אבינא גדול מה שנאמר במיכאל יותר ממה שנאמר בגבריאל דאילו במיכאל כתי' (ישעיהו ו, ו) ויעף אלי אחד מן השרפים ואלו גבי גבריאל כתי' (דניאל ט, כא) והאיש גבריאל אשר ראיתי בחזון בתחלה מועף ביעף וגו' מאי משמע דהאי אחד מיכאל הוא אמר ר' יוחנן אתיא אחד אחד כתיב הכא ויעף אלי אחד מן השרפים וכתי' התם (דניאל י, יג) והנה מיכאל אחד (מן) השרים הראשונים בא לעזרני תנא מיכאל באחת גבריאל בשתים אליהו בארבע ומלאך המות בשמנה ובשעת המגפה באחת (ברכות ד עמוד ב

Comment: For a very long (if not exhaustive) list of angels appearing in post-Biblical sources, [this](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?155246&lang=eng) is exactly the book you want.

Answer (score 10):

The only place angels are mentioned by name in Tanakh is in Daniel (chs 8-10). In the Yerushalmi, we find a statement of Resh Laqish that the names of the angels we brought back from the Babylonian exile, and were unknown in pre-exilic Israel ([Yerushalmi Rosh haShana 1:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A3_%D7%95_%D7%90)). The later one moves, the more names of angels there are, beginning with a few more in the writings from Qumran, then more in the Bavli, then many more in Kabbalistic literature.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, by the way. I'm glad to see you've registered your account and have already provided some enlightening answers. I look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 2):

[This link from Wikipedia](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) has a long list, however I do not know if it is accurate as I do not know the source for it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more well-known angels are Gabriel, Refael, Uriel, and Michael; however, there are many angels.  They serve many purposes in Scripture, including being messengers, fighters, and other roles.

An exhaustive list would be quite long. Here is [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theological_angels) attempt at it. That list includes angels from many religions, but it lists the religion to which each angel is applicable, so you can find it there.

Comment: exhaustive list?

Comment: @Ali, if that's what you want, please say so in the question and explain why.

Comment: @Ali, I have added to my answer, although I don't know for sure that this list is exhaustive.

Comment: only jewish as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

you might find some answers here http://www.scribd.com/doc/53748980/A-Dictionary-of-Angels-Including-the-Fallen-Angels-by-Gustav-Davidson,  just look for kaballa sources not other religions