# Names of angels

Tags: names, malach-angel, babylonian-exile

There is a pretty well known point made in the Talmud Yerushalmi Rosh Hashana 1:2
stating that the names we are accustomed to calling the months of our lunar calendar came up with those returning from Babylon.

> דא"ר חנינה שמות חדשים עלו בידם מבבל. בראשונה בירח האיתנים שבו נולדו אבות מתו אבות נפקדו אימהות. בראשונה (מלכים א ו) בירח בול שבו העלה נובל והארץ עשויה בולות בולות. שבו בוללים לבהמה מתוך הבית. בראשונה (שם) בירח זיו שבו זיוו של עולם הצמחים ניכרין והאילנות ניכרין. מיכן והילך (נחמיה ב) ויהי בחדש ניסן שנת עשרים (נחמיה א) ויהי בחדש כסליו שנת עשרים (אסתר ב) בחדש העשירי הוא חדש טבת.

The corresponding names are easily found. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_calendar) for instance.

However another statement is made immediately afterwards concerning the names of the angels which are said to have come from Babylon as well.

> רשב"ל אמר אף שמות המלאכים עלו בידן מבבל. בראשונה (ישעיהו ו) ויעף אלי אחד מן השרפים (שם) שרפים עומדים ממעל לו מיכן והילך (דנייאל ט) והאיש גבריאל (דנייאל י) כי אם מיכאל שרכם.

Concerning this statement I have been unable to find any reference to ancient Babylonian text that concur with this idea.

In fact according to [this](http://jhom.com/topics/angels/talmud_fourangels.htm#3a) site, the statement was made  without any factual source.

> We find no mention of angels' names until we reach the Book of Daniel, where Michael and Gabriel make their appearance. This fact led the Rabbis to assert that the names of the angels were something that the returning exiles brought with them from Babylonia.

Do we in fact have any evidence to tie the names we use for angels to Babylonian sources?

Edit: To compound the issue somewhat, [Ramban in Exodus 30:13](http://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.30.13.1?lang=bi) says the angelic names Michael and Gavriel are Lashon Hakodesh, not Babylonian in origin.

> וכן הטעם אצלי במה שרבותינו קוראין לשון התורה ''לשון הקודש'', שהוא מפני שדברי התורה והנבואות וכל דברי קדושה כולם בלשון ההוא נאמרו והנה הוא הלשון שהקב''ה יתעלה שמו מדבר בו עם נביאיו ועם עדתו אנכי ולא יהיה לך ושאר דברות התורה והנבואה, ובו נקרא בשמותיו הקדושים אל, אלהים, צבאות, ושדי, ויו''ד ה''א, והשם הגדול המיוחד, ובו ברא עולמו (ב''ר יח ו), וקרא שמות שמים וארץ וכל אשר בם, **ומלאכיו וכל צבאיו לכולם בשם יקרא מיכאל וגבריאל בלשון ההוא**, ובו קרא שמות לקדושים אשר בארץ אברהם יצחק ויעקב ושלמה וזולתם:

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26374/759

Comment: I am not sure about the names themselves, but, as you are probably aware, the ancient Babylonians were master astronomers, and Judaism, just like Christianity, preserves a belief in [seven archangels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Archangels) (mirroring the [seven classical planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_planet), known since antiquity), which are mentioned in (post)exilic books (not necessarily canonical), such as Daniel, Tobit, and Enoch.

Comment: The same type of symbolism was embodied by the seven-branched [Menorah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menorah).